# Can i partition windows and ubuntu and have the same data in them?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I have Windows 7 32-bit, and I want to have ubuntu as a partition. My question is that I have some files in Windows that i also want on Ubuntu, is this possible ??
And if possible then how ?

Comment: both systems are already installed ?

Comment: No. Windows is installed, I am about to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @VineetMohan fine , just make a separate partition for Ubuntu.so that you can view all the files with out extra ground work.

Comment: when you install ubuntu you can choose where windows partitions should be auto-mounted, so you'll be able to use them (read/write) any time, without any hacks

but, you also can do this anytime after instalation, here you have a video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qwr3e7oPN0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, install **DiskInternals**(software) in windows and **open that ubuntu partition** to access the ubuntu files. **In ubuntu** you can simply **mount windows local drive** partition and use. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you more specicfic how to mount the windows partition under linux .. and does it have to be done after installing ubuntu.

Comment: Simply open nautilus (File browser) and in the left you will see the Windows partition, double click it, now give the root partition and it gets mounted. Voila!

Comment: actually this is my first time i am about to use ubuntu so can you be more clear as to what root partition should i give.

Comment: Sorry misspelt **root password**.

Comment: Please edit your answer to put the additional instructions! In a comment they will get lost eventually.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Windows 7 32-bit, and I want to have ubuntu as a partition.

as you mentioned , you want to install Ubuntu in a separate partition , so no problem you can access all the other partitions and files from the installed Ubuntu including windows partition also.

Ubuntu supports NTFS.

Comment: If ntfs-3g is pre-installed which is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a third data partition which is FAT or NTFS formatted and dump all your data in.
Or you can mount you windows partition under Ubuntu. Since Linux can use Windows Filesystems, but Windows can't use Unix filesystems this would be possible, too.
For the commands how to mount the windows partition we need more info. For example `fdisk -l`.
But `# mount /dev/Windows_Partition /path/where/you/want/to/mount/` would work.

Comment: Sorry, as i see, you haven't installed it yet. But still: You can create a third partition (Which would be better i think) or simply mount the windows partition under linux

Comment: Can you more specicfic how to mount the windows partition under linux .. and does it have to be done after installing ubuntu.